# How long does it take until the tank contains the same amount of both liquid A and liquid B?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

> A tank initially contains 400 litres of liquid A. Liquid B is pumped
> into the tank at the rate of 20 litres per minute. The contents of the
> tank is pumped out at the same rate of 20 litres per minute. The
> mixture is stirred continuously and the tank is kept full at 400
> litres at all times. Let X (t) denote the amount (in litres) of liquid
> A in the tank after t minutes.

How long does it take until the tank contains the same amount of both liquid A and liquid B?

This is a problem I've seen and solved a few times in different forms and while I understand how to solve it mechanically I don't know why certain choices are made.

I determine that:

$ X(t) = 400(1 - e^{-t/20})$

I know from here to answer the above question I would need to solve for $t$ in the below equation:

$200 = 400(1 - e^{-t/20})$

As I understand it $X(t)$ is the mixture of $A$ and $B$ at a point in time. So if $X(t)$ makes up 200L of the 400L then the tank would be 50% $A$ and 50% ($A$,$B$)

Why have we chosen 200 for $X(t)$?

For how much of this problem is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: This is an exercise that helps you understand calculus. Take a short period of time - short enough that you think a very insignificant amount of the liquid B pumped in, will be pumped out in the same period.  Make a straightforward calculation of the change in concentration per unit time.  Now calculate your change per unit time, in the limit as $t\to0$. That gives you the derivative indicating the rate of change of concentration.

Comment: Your $X(t)$ seems to be incorrect. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x(t)$ be the volume of liquid A in the tank. The concentration (a.k.a the fraction) of liquid A in the tank is $\rho(t)=\frac{x(t)}{V}$ where $V$ represents the volume of the tank.

At $t+\Delta t$, the amount of liquid A leaves the tank  is $\rho(t)\times q\times \Delta t$ where $q$ represents the rate of liquid leaving the tank.

The amount of liquid A in the tank at $t+\Delta t$ is $x(t+\Delta t)$.
\begin{align}
x(t+\Delta t)
&=x(t)- \rho(t) \times q \times \Delta t\\
&=x(t)- \frac{x(t)}{V} \times q\times \Delta t\\
\frac{x(t+\Delta t)-x(t)}{\Delta t} &= -\frac{q}{V}x(t)
\end{align}

Taking $\Delta t \to 0$, we have
\begin{align}
x'(t)&=-\frac{20}{400}x(t)\\
x(t)&=C e^{-t/20}\\
&= 400 e^{-t/20}
\end{align}

At $t=T$ minutes, the amount of liquid A equals to the amount of liquid B.

\begin{align}
x(T)&= 400 e^{-T/20}\\
200 &= 400 e^{-T/20}\\
T&= 20 \ln 2\\
&\approx 13.9
\end{align}

#### Edit

At the end of the world, the amount of liquid A in the tank must be zero. Let's check.

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty} x(t) &= \lim_{x\to \infty} 400 e^{-t/20}\\
&= 0
\end{align}

I strongly believe that your equation $x(t)=400\big(1-e^{-t/20}\big)$ is not correct.

Comment: Your x(t) is the amount of liquid A at time t. The OP's X(t) is the amount of liquid B at time t.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: But the question said $X(t)$ is the amount of liquid A in the tank.

Comment: Oh, I missed that it was defined in the question. You're right.

Comment: Thank you this cleared up quite a bit for me regarding the understanding of these problems as well as another problem of understanding I had. My equation that you say is incorrect is that the amount of B at time t? that would explain why I reach the same answer